# How do I access the Twig path() function from a Controller?

Tags: symfony

Okay, I know I can't literally call a twig template function from a controller, but to make links, I usually do the `{{ path('_routeName') }}` and that's great.

However, now I want to formulate some links in the controller that will then be passed to the template via parameters like this:

```
$params = array(
    'breadcrumbs' = array(
        'Donuts' => '/donuts',
        'Bearclaws' => '/donuts/bearclaws',
        'Strawberry bearclaw' => null,
    ),
);
return $this->render('Bundle:Donut:info.html.twig', $params);
```

Except I don't want to hard-code those links. What I'd like is to be able to do

```
        'Donuts' => path('_donutRoute'),
```

but how to reach the path method or equivalent?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If your controller is extending the `Symfony2` Controller (`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`) you can use the following to generate urls like this :

`$this->generateUrl('_donutRoute')`

Comment: And if not, `$this->container->get('router')->generate('_donutRoute');` will do you just fine.

Answer (score 13):

If you want it with parameters use the following:

```
$this->generateUrl('_donutRoute', array('param1'=>'val1', 'param2'=>'val2'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an alternative way to do this that I feel is equal to the one proposed by @d.syph.3r

The plan is to do:

```
'breadcrumbs' = array(
    'Donuts' => 'donutsRoute',
    'Bearclaws' => 'bearclawRoute',
    'Strawberry bearclaw' => null,
)
```

Then in the twig template, do:

```
{% for name, route in breadcrumbs %}
   {{ path(route) }}
```

The advantage here is that the Controller is not generating any HTML in this case.